# Update with from clause within user defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, babelfish

Writting function which should compatibile with Babelfish and SQL Server as well.

The following function is having update statement with from and joins clause.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_update_from_test()
RETURNS @ListOWeekDays TABLE
(
    DyNumber INT,
    DayAbb VARCHAR(40), 
    WeekName VARCHAR(40)
) 
AS BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO @ListOWeekDays
    VALUES 
    (1,'Mon','Monday')  ,
    (2,'Tue','Tuesday') ,
    (3,'Wed','Wednesday') ,
    (4,'Thu','Thursday'),
    (5,'Fri','Friday'),
    (6,'Sat','Saturday'),
    (7,'Sun','Sunday')  

    UPDATE  lwd
    SET DayAbb = COALESCE( lwd1.DayAbb, lwd2.DayAbb ) + '--',
        WeekName = COALESCE( lwd3.WeekName, lwd2.WeekName ) + '-^-'
    FROM @ListOWeekDays lwd
    LEFT JOIN @ListOWeekDays lwd1 ON lwd1.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber
    LEFT JOIN @ListOWeekDays lwd2 ON lwd2.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber
    LEFT JOIN @ListOWeekDays lwd3 ON lwd3.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber;

RETURN;

END
GO
```

Works fine in SQL Server but getting an error in Babelfish:

> 'UPDATE' cannot be used within a function

When I tried it with following syntax it works in Babelfish but not for SQL Server.

--Works in Babelfish

```
UPDATE  ListOWeekDays
SET DayAbb = COALESCE( lwd1.DayAbb, lwd2.DayAbb ) + '--',
    WeekName = COALESCE( lwd3.WeekName, lwd2.WeekName ) + '-^-'
FROM @ListOWeekDays lwd
LEFT JOIN @ListOWeekDays lwd1 ON lwd1.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber
LEFT JOIN @ListOWeekDays lwd2 ON lwd2.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber
LEFT JOIN @ListOWeekDays lwd3 ON lwd3.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber;
```

--Error in SQL Server:

> Msg 8154, Level 16, State 1, Line 52    The table '@ListOWeekDays' is
> ambiguous.

**Note**: The logic of update statement is different in original code, I have just added the sample code for understanding of issue.

Comment: @DaleK, As I said in note, there is large query written on the top of table variable, can't add it here, so just added simplified version of that query.

Comment: @DaleK, The function is used in other queries with JOINs. And also don't know what all other dependencies it has.

Comment: Must be mussing something here but the outer joins will always join, you may as well just return a static list?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make modifications inside a function, only in a procedure.

You can just do a joined update, and use an `OUTPUT` clause to get the changed results.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE update_from_test
-- parameters here
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

UPDATE  lwd
SET
  DayAbb = COALESCE( lwd1.DayAbb, lwd2.DayAbb ) + '--',
  WeekName = COALESCE( lwd3.WeekName, lwd2.WeekName ) + '-^-'
OUTPUT
  inserted.DyNumber,
  inserted.DayAbb,
  inserted.WeekName
FROM ListOWeekDays lwd
LEFT JOIN ListOWeekDays lwd1 ON lwd1.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber
LEFT JOIN ListOWeekDays lwd2 ON lwd2.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber
LEFT JOIN ListOWeekDays lwd3 ON lwd3.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using CTE.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT lwd.DyNumber dn,lwd1.DayAbb as da1, lwd2.DayAbb da2, lwd3.WeekName wn1, lwd2.WeekName wn2
    FROM @ListOWeekDays lwd
    LEFT JOIN @ListOWeekDays lwd1 ON lwd1.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber
    LEFT JOIN @ListOWeekDays lwd2 ON lwd2.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber
    LEFT JOIN @ListOWeekDays lwd3 ON lwd3.DyNumber = lwd.DyNumber
)
UPDATE @ListOWeekDays
SET     DayAbb          = COALESCE( cte.da1, CTE.da2 ) + '--'
    ,   WeekName    = COALESCE( CTE.wn1, CTE.wn2 ) + '-^-'
FROM CTE 
WHERE DyNumber = cte.dn;
```

Eventually works fine in both (SQL Server and Babelfish).

Comment: You do know a semi-colon is a statement *terminator*? Not a *begininator*.

Comment: The previous statement must be terminated before a WITH/CTE. To avoid errors, most folk use ;WITH because we don't know what is before the CTE

Comment: @Nitika - some folks do... But that's not it's correct useage, all statements should now be terminated with a srmi-colon. Many folks do this. And in this case, given its a self answer, OP definitely knows what code comes before.

Comment: But In sql this is not mandatory to terminate the statement :)

Comment: @Nitika just because it's not mandatory doesn't mean one should ignore best practice.

Comment: You can update the `CTE` directly, as long as it only updates the columns of one table reference from within it. `UPDATE CTE SET ...`

Answer (score 0):

This is a current bug in Babelfish: while you cannot modify an actual table in a SQL function, you can do anything to a table variable in a SQL function. Unfortunately, the syntax `UPDATE t...FROM @tabvar` as t is currently interpreted by Babelfish as that a normal table is updated. This bug is expected to be fixed in the next release, which is v.3.2.0.
The workaround is to do a direct `UPDATE @tabvar`, so not using the correlation name for the UPDATE.